# Struts 2 How to display map checkboxlist

Tags: java, jsp, scope, struts2, hashmap

I have the following code in action:

```
private Map<Long,String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();

public Map<Long, String> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(Map<Long, String> map) {
    this.map= map;
}

public String list() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list= objectDAO.listSomething();                        
            for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                Object row = (Object) list.get(i);
                Long id = row.getId();
                String name = row.getName();
                map.put(id, name);
            }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

After checking with debugger I can see that map is filled with the correct keys and values.

My jsp where the problem occurrs is here:

```xml
<s:checkboxlist list = "map" 
             listKey = "%{id.toString()}" 
           listValue = "%{name}" 
                name = "name" 
               value = "name" 
               label = "Label"/>
```

I have also tried something like this, but with no luck:

```xml
<s:iterator value="map">
     <s:checkbox  label="Label" name="name" value="%{value}"/>
     <s:property value="%{value}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

The error when hitting the action is this (edited):

> Error on line 28, column 13 in template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl stack.findValue(parameters.listKey) is undefined. It cannot be assigned to itemKey - Class: freemarker.core.Assignment File: Assignment.java Method: accept Line: 111 - freemarker/core/Assignment.java:111:-1

Any ideas how to fix this? I have converted code to generic code. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting same error with second code segment as well?

Comment: Sorry no,  I have no errors with second segment, but checkboxes are not shown at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` and `name` are the names of the variables you've used serverside to populate the map...

They've nothing to do with the map attributes you're reading in the JSP, that are `key` and `value`:

```xml
<s:checkboxlist list = "map" 
             listKey = "%{key}" 
           listValue = "%{value}" 
                name = "value" 
               value = "name" 
               label = "Label"/>
```

Comment: @manu You can use map in `<s:checkboxlist>`'s  `list` attribute, no need to put `listKey` and `listValue`.